# Will a 29x2.5 tyre fit a 29x3.0 rim size

Tags: tire, beginner, tyre-width

I just need to know if the smaller width would fit the fat wheel size because I can't find the type of tire I want

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What is the actual rim size as written on it?  It seems to me that 3" would be a tyre size, not an internal rim size, which would be in mm and probably no larger than 50mm.

Comment: Oh yeah mate I have a 29x3.0 on my rim rn and I was wondering if I could change it to a 29x2.5